# How to convert array of arrays to array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have an array like this

```
var array = [["Fitim",13],["Faltin Developer",1],["Local",1]]
```

i want to get an object like this:

```
var totalUsers= [{ Fitim:13},{Faltin Developer: 1},{Local:1}]
```

how can i do this

Comment: pls add an example in the question and do not refere to an other site.

Comment: What is `{Faltin Developer: 1}`? At least not valid JS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Welcome to SO. We help with code that __you've__ written that you're having problems with. _We don't write all your code._ You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Use `Object.fromEntries` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Comment: {Faltin Developer: 1} just an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a simple `map` function to achieve this:

```js
const userArray = [
  ["Fitim", 13],
  ["Faltin Developer", 1],
  ["Local", 1]
];

console.log(
  userArray.map((user) => ({
    [user[0]]: user[1],
  }))
);
```

Comment: Why not Object.fromEntries(userArray)?

Comment: Because it is asked for an array of objects not one object.